# How do i get the xcode profiling tools to show c++ objects

Tags: c++, xcode, profiling, instruments

I am currently starting to write a game in xcode for ios. I would like to write the main game engine in c++ for portability reasons.

My problem begins when I profile the app. Xcode Instruments are a great set of tools for profiling, but as the bulk of my objects are c++ and not objective-C its near enough impossible to use the allocations tool as these objects all come up as < non-object >.

I noticed that there is a check box called "identify c++ objects" but that dosent seem to do anything..

Would be great know how you guys profile your apps when writing c++ iphone apps?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Allocations instrument, Instruments initially shows memory allocation statistics. The statistics tell you how much memory your app is using. After learning how much memory your app uses, you most likely want to know the areas of your code that allocate memory and how much memory they're allocating. Switching to the call tree view, which you can do from the jump bar, makes it easier to determine where you are allocating memory in your code. More detailed information is available in the following article:

[Instruments: Finding Where You Allocate Memory](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/12/instruments-finding-where-you-allocate-memory/)